# python scrapy how to remove extra parsed character

Tags: python, scrapy

During a parsing process using scrapy I have found this output

> [u'TARTARINI AUTO SPA (CENTRALINO SELEZIONE PASSANTE)'],"[u'V. C.BONAZZI\xa043', u'40013', u'CASTEL MAGGIORE']",[u'0516322411'],[u'info@tartariniauto.it'],[u'CARS (LPG INSTALLERS)'],[u'track.aspx?id=0&url=http://www.tartariniauto.it']

As you see there are some extra character like

> u'  \xa043  "  '  [  ]

Which I don't want .
How can I remove these ??
Besides there are 5 items in this string . I want the string look like this :

> item1 , item2 , item3 , item4 , item5

Here is my pipelines.py code

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
import re
import json
import csv

class InfobelPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.file = csv.writer(open('items.csv','wb'))
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
      name = item['name']
      address = item['address']
      phone = item['phone']
      email = item['email']
      category = item['category']
      website = item['website']
      self.file.writerow((name,address,phone,email,category,website))
    return item
```

Thanks

Comment: Just iterate through your string and remove A) every character that throws an error when you `str()` it or B) every character above a certain ordinal.

Comment: @JoelCornett that is very un-pythonic

Comment: I fear you're asking how to remove things like square brackets and quotes? That is, you're asking how to remove the strings from their encased lists, or you have outputted them to an external file and are re-reading them in? All this kind of work should be done in your item loader anyway, not in your pipeline, in my opinion.

Comment: @Edwardr:  Well how do you propose it should be done? I guarantee that any solution you come up with will involve what I just mentioned. How pythonic it is or isn't depends only on the combination of builtins one uses to do this.

Comment: @JoelCornett sorry, I didn't mean *very*. My point was - why add an extra loop when `"data".encode('ascii', error='ignore')` will do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra characters you're seeing are unicode strings. You'll see them a lot if you're scraping on the web. Common examples include copyright symbols: © unicode point `U+00A9`, or trademark symbols ™ unicode point `U+2122`.

The quickest way to remove them is to try to encode them to ascii and then throw them away if they're not ascii characters (which none of them are)

```
>>> example = u"Xerox ™ printer"
>>> example
u'Xerox \u2122 printer'
>>> example.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 6: ordinal 
not in range(128)
>>> example.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
'Xerox  printer'
>>>
```

As you can see, when you try to decode the symbol to ascii it raises a `UnicodeEncodeError` because the character can't be represented in ascii. However, if you add the `errors='ignore'` keyword argument then it will simply ignore symbols it can't encode.

Comment: This is the edited [code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/960572/) Working fine . But showed this [error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/960570/) one time.

Comment: @MarufRahman an `IndexError` at position `0` means that the array is empty. If item behaves like the builtin `dict`, which I can't remember if Scrapy `Items` do, then you could swap `item['xx'][0]` for `item.get('xx', [''])` for each of the lines.

Comment: That came across as a little rude on my part. Anyway + 1 for the answer.

Comment: @MarufRahman sorry, I missed a pair of brackets off my example. `website = item.get('website', [''])[0].encode('ascii',errors='ignore')` is what you want. Feel free to mark my answer as correct if that's what it finally is. ;-)